# string.split('/') not giving proper array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I'm having an issue with the following script.
The calling script is:
script src="//192.168.6.10/js/cYJIeCa30E.js
the resulting script needs to be parsed for cYJIeCa30E.js 
in this script I have:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var lastScript = scripts[scripts.length-1];
var scriptName = lastScript.src;

var name = scriptName.split('/');
alert(name);
```

alert(name) gives comma separated values:

```
http:,,192.168.6.10,js,cYJIeCa30E.js
```

but

alert(name[4]) gives ':' not the value after the last '/'

any idea what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: [Don't use `name` in the global space.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) Try changing your variable to something other than `name` and see if it works.

Comment: You need to extract ` cYJIeCa30E.js` from `src="//192.168.6.10/js/cYJIeCa30E.js` right?

Comment: @mike-c - perfect!

Comment: recomendation: read the last position, based on array size to read the last position by reuse in dynamic routes.

Comment: @phpmydev just like the post @mike-c posted, you should not use` name in the global space`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way will be like so:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var lastScript = scripts[scripts.length-1];
var scriptName = lastScript.src;

var a = scriptName.split('/');
alert(a[4]); //cYJIeCa30E.js
```

**Note** You can change the variable `a` to any other variable. Thanks to `Mike C` for the MDN link